# Neo4J I'm trying to delete replies from a post without deleting the user or other relationships in the reply

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node, lets call it a `(p:Post)` and that node has a relationship to another post called `[r:REPLIED_WITH]` this other post will be `(reply:Post)`. `reply` may have more nodes with the same relationship. This could technically be an endless amount of replies. I want to delete `(p)` and every reply and every reply of a reply in a cascading way. I know about `DETACH DELETE`, however it says it's not for large datasets and I want to be sure it doesn't delete something it really shouldn't because it pretty much says it deletes all relationships and nodes attached to it which doesn't sound like something I should do if a user creates a post.

For visual This is what I want deleted
`(p:Post)<-[r:REPLIED_WITH]-(reply:Post)<-[r2:REPLIED_WITH]-(reply2:Post)<-[r3:REPLIED_WITH]-(reply3:Post)...`

I just want to delete the initial post and all posts that replied to the post and all replies to the replies to the posts and the replies of those replies. It could be endless levels deep.

I cannot figure out a looped logic to it other than

```
MATCH (p:Post)
WHERE ID(p) = {postID}
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[r:replied_To]-(reply:Post)
DELETE p, r
RETURN ID(reply)
```

after that checking if the result is empty and then doing the same query in a loop. That just doesn't seem the most efficient way to tackle the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use variable-length relationships to identify the nodes you want to delete.

You'll also want to use DETACH DELETE in place of deleting relationship and nodes individually, as nodes cannot be deleted until all relationships from them are deleted.

If this were to be done all at once, the query would look like this:

```
// lower bound of 0 so the post itself is included in toDelete
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:replied_To*0..]-(toDelete:Post)
WHERE ID(p) = {postID}
DETACH DELETE toDelete
RETURN ID(toDelete)
```

If your graph is large enough where the operation is likely to timeout or fail, then you may consider a mark-then-delete approach.

First, label the nodes to delete instead of deleting them:

```
MATCH (p:Post)<-[:replied_To*0..]-(toDelete:Post)
WHERE ID(p) = {postID}
SET toDelete:ToDelete
```

After you install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), you should be able to use the [periodic.commit()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) procedure to batch deletion of the nodes you've labeled :ToDelete:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (x:ToDelete) 
WITH x LIMIT {limit}
DETACH DELETE x
RETURN COUNT(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

You can adjust your limit as desired, if it's too large of a chunk.

EDIT

It's important to note possible race conditions here, specifically the scenario where you mark nodes in the reply chain as :ToDelete, then after another user replies somewhere in the chain. The new reply (or replies) were created after you labeled the nodes, and won't be deleted in your batch delete operation.

To deal with these cases, you may need to run some cleanup queries at the end to find dangling replies, where the post they replied to is gone. It's also useful to label all replies with :Reply as well as :Post, so you can match on them later like so:

```
MATCH (x:Reply) 
WHERE NOT ()<-[:replied_To]-(x)
// we've found dangling replies, now delete their chains
MATCH (x)<-[:replied_To*0..]-(toDelete:Reply)
DETACH DELETE toDelete
```

By having replies be multi-labeled like this, it allows us to run queries on reply nodes only, and not consider nodes that are only :Posts but not replies.

Comment: That perodic commit is awesome. I had no idea that existed. So every post has a user though will the DETACH DELETE delete the User too? I'm under the belief that DETACH DELETE deletes all relationships and nodes to which those nodes are attached which if they are connected the users would be deleted as well. Is that accurate?

Comment: my users are connected with (p:Post)<-[:WROTE]-(u:User)

Comment: Not accurate. DETACH DELETE will only delete the nodes you are deleting, and all the relationships attached to them. It does not cascade the delete to connected nodes not included in the query. In my example above, only nodes labeled :ToDelete will be deleted, as well as the relationships to other nodes, so all :Users who wrote posts will remain, as none of them are labeled :ToDelete.

Comment: OK, but if `toDelete` had a Post with the [:replied_To] relationship would those posts delete as well? I want to avoid having Posts that were meant to be replies showing up in the database because only the [:replied_To] relationship was deleted but not the reply as well.

Comment: Because of the variable-length relationship when marking nodes as :ToDelete, it will label all nodes in the :replied_To chain. That said, there are some race conditions that may occur that can leave you with dangling replies. I edited my post to talk about that at the end.

Comment: So I tested this using `CREATE (p:Post {body: 'This is a post'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply:Post {body: 'This is a reply'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply2:Post {body: 'This is a reply2'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply3:Post {body: 'This is a reply3'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply4:Post {body: 'This is a reply4'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply5:Post {body: 'This is a reply5'})<-[:REPLIED_TO]-(reply6:Post {body: 'This is a reply6'})` to create the nodes and then used `MATCH (p:Post)<-[:replied_To*0..]-(toDelete:Post)
WHERE ID(p) = 1
DETACH DELETE toDelete` and it only deleted the original post

Comment: You're using different relationship types. The relationships you created are :REPLIED_TO, but in the match you used for deletion, the relationship type is :replied_To. Neo4j is case sensitive, make sure these are the same.

Comment: Ok sorry about that It is working now. I must have missed that. I apologize

Comment: Added users and tested it. This works perfectly. Thank you for your help. Accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.